# Why the Text color in tablayout is different from the color.xml that i have defined?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-tablayout

I want to change the textColor shows in TabLayout, but there is a problem, the colors are different from what I've defined in colors.xml.

Mainactivity.java:

```
 TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(R.color.tab_normal, R.color.tab_se);
```

colors.xml:

```
<color name="tab_normal">#e2e2e2</color>
<color name="tab_se">#ffffff</color>
```

And this is TabLayout, the Colors are different.
[enter image description here]

But if:

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);
```

then text color in Tablayout is normal, it is white.

Sorry for my poor English.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhB60.png

Comment: You should use  `ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivityName.this,R.color.tab_normal)`

Comment: BTW `getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_normal)` is deprecated. Instead use `ContextCompat.getColor()`..

Comment: What is the version of Support Library that you are using currently?

Comment: or just simply use in xml.. `app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_se"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_normal"`

Comment: @Piyush ji edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.selector));
```

Comment: tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.tab_normal),ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.tab_se));

Answer (score 0):

You can use in XML layout also.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_se"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_normal" />
```